# PHP PDO limit connection time

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading

I have a script that remotely calls a database on another server using PDO.  At some point in the future I will thread this process, but for now that is not a luxury I have.

Basically, if the connection is good at all it's going to go through in less than a second; maybe 3-4 if there's a delay on the network but rarely that.

However, if the connection is bad, i.e. remote server down, PDO is going to keep trying - which will cause user frustration.

I would like to give PDO say 5 seconds to connect, and if it can't, die and go to exception handling and proceed on.  (Since the contents of remote database are not *essential* to the application)

Any way to do this?  set_time_limit() will not work, it will limit time for the script as a whole!